# Speeding up a transfer of a file to Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am uploading a file to my Google Cloud Platform VM using scp on Linux. However, after initially uploading it at a speed of 900 kb/s it quickly falls to 20kb/s. My internet upload speed should be around 20mbps. I wanted to upload an SQLite database clocking in at 20gb, but this is unfeasible at this point.

Right now I used 54 minutes to upload a 94 MB file. It cannot be that slow?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue multiple times with GCP, the solution I use is to compress all my files, upload it to dropbox and then wget the file from there. The speeds should go back to normal.

This answer should help you ae well, though I don't know if your paticular issue is related to gcp , scp or both.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/760509/how-to-make-scp-go-faster